# Android directory creation on SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am using File.mkdirs() to make a directory on my SD card. mkdirs() returns a value of true, and when I read the directory the next execution the directory is there. However, I cannot see the directory from my PC, or from the built-in file browser.

Android SDK version is 25. I have successfully requested permission for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Why am I not able to see the directory from the PC?

My code:

```
File resDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "BLC/res/" + mSpeciesID);
if (resDir.exists()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu: EXISTS");
} else {
    if (!resDir.mkdirs()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu: mkdirs FAILURE ");
    };
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu: "+ resDir.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

From the log:

First execution:

```
D/BLC: onCreateOptionsMenu: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/BLC/res/206
```

Subsequent executions:

```
D/BLC: onCreateOptionsMenu: EXISTS
```

Comment: That is indeed a path to external storage. And not to a removable storage like a micro SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a directory in Android device, you need to refresh your media so that your folder get visible in PC(windows)
so after you are done with making the directory call the following method with directory path.

```
public static void refreshSystemMediaScanDataBase(Context context, String docPath)
{
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(docPath));
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Comment: OK, this worked perfectly to show the directory. However, the `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is returning a path to the internal storage, and not to the SD card. Any thoughts?